# Как добавить класс(прописать условие) к header на главной WP?

Tags: wordpress

Всем добрый день
У меня на сайте есть header, который отличается на главной странице от внутренних. Как правильно нужно прописать условие чтобы на главной добавлялся к header один класс а на внутренних его не было или же наоборот?

Answer (score 2):

```
<header class="<?php echo is_front_page() ? 'front-page-class' : 'other-page-class'; ?>">...</header>
```

Подробнее о функции [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)